# KnockoutJS radio buttons not changing like checkboxes do

Tags: knockout.js

I have the same data structure for checkboxes and radio buttons. When checking the checkboxes, they return correct boolean value ('chosen' variable).

However, when I check the radio buttons, 'chosen' always changes to the 'value' (integer).

Also the radio buttons don't get "checked" in the beginning, even though 'chosen' == true

**Javascript:**

```
function attributeValueViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.attributeID = ko.observable(data.attributeID);
    self.value = ko.observable(data.value);
    self.chosen = ko.observable(data.chosen);
}

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.attributeValues1 = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.attributeValues2 = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.addToList = function(data) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(item) {           
            self.attributeValues1.push(new attributeValueViewModel(item));
            self.attributeValues2.push(new attributeValueViewModel(item));
        });
    };
}

var arr = [
    {
        "id": 55,
        "attributeID": 28,
        "value": "Yes",
        "chosen": false,
    },
    {
        "id": 56,
        "attributeID": 28,
        "value": "No",
        "chosen": true,
    },
    {
        "id": 62,
        "attributeID": 28,
        "value": "Maybe",
        "chosen": false,
    }
];

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.addToList(arr);
```

**HTML**

```
<b>Checkbox:</b>
<div id="test1">
    <span data-bind="foreach: attributeValues1()">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id(), checked: chosen, attr: { name: 'test1' }" />
    <span data-bind="text: value()"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: chosen()"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<br />
<b>Radio:</b>
<div id="test2">
    <span data-bind="foreach: attributeValues2()">
    <input type="radio" data-bind="value: id(), checked: chosen, attr: { name: 'test2' }" />
    <span data-bind="text: value()"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: chosen()"></span>
    </span>
</div>​
```

**Here is my fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/SN7Vn/1/

Can you please explain this behavior and why the radio buttons don't update boolean (like checkboxes do)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check boxes and Radio buttons behave differently from each other.  When a single observable is bound to the `checked` binding (as opposed to an array) is where they particularly behave differently.

For a check box, it will always be a boolean value indicating whether it was checked or not.  Simple.  If an array, the `value` will be added/removed from the array.

However for a radio button, the it will be the value assigned to the radio button.  For a single observable, it will only be considered checked the value of what it is bound to is equal to the value.  In your case, your value is bound to the `id` so will only respond if the `chosen` value is equal to the corresponding id.  For an array, it will add/remove the value to the array.

Since nothing else alters the value of the `chosen` for the corresponding attribute, it remains the same

I tweaked your example to demonstrate a bit how the value can affect the checked state.  [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/SN7Vn/2/)

It's all spelled out [in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html), look at it closer.

---

If you want it to work similarly to how it does for checkboxes, it will take a bit of work to get it right.  I have this code which feels a bit fragile due to how the bindings work and how their order dependentness can cause problems.  You can try this out, I'm just not sure how robust this is.

For this to work, you'll need an observable to keep track of the actual changes to what radio button is actually selected.  Then you can subscribe to changes on that observable to update the observable of your choice.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.radiochecked = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        // the checked binding depends on the element having an initial value
        // we need to allow bindings that potentially set it to be applied first
        setTimeout(function () {
            var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (options.checked()) {
                options.selected(element.value);
            }
            options.selected.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                options.checked(newValue === element.value);
            });
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { checked: options.selected });
        }, 0);
    }
};
```

Then bind it to your radio buttons:

```html
<input type="radio" data-bind="
    value: id,
    radiochecked: { 
        'checked': chosen,
        'selected': $root.attributeValues2.selected
    },
    attr: { name: 'test2' }" />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/u3Pde/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All I want is the 'chosen' to be true/false whether the "box" is checked - just like the checkboxes. Also if I added a dropdown, I would like the value to be true/false whether the value was selected in the list. Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible to get that behavior but will take a bit of work.

Comment: I have a possible solution to do what you want but it seems very fragile due to the unknown order in which the bindings are applied and how the `checked` binding works.  I'm a little hesitant to share this because of that.

Answer (score 1):

This may also help. The binding below will take a group of radio buttons, on changing one of them, set the observable behind all the rest in the group to a particular value (null, false, 0, ...)

As it stands, it requires the value of the observable to be true/false in order for it to select the right radio button.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkedRadio = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).change(function () {
            //Get all radio buttons int he group
            var group = $(element).attr('name');
            var radios = $('input[type="radio"][name="' + group + '"]').not($(element));

            //Reset all values for other radio buttons in this group
            $.each(radios, function (i, radio) {
                var $r = $(radio);
                if (!$r.prop('checked')) {
                    var data = ko.dataFor(radio);
                    data[allBindingsAccessor().checkedRadioProperty](allBindingsAccessor().checkedRadioValue);
                }
            });

            //Update bound data
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var checked = $(element).prop('checked');
            value(checked);
        });

        //Select radio button based on bound data
        var value = unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $(element).prop('checked', value);
    }
};
```

To use the binding you could something like:

```
<input type="radio" value="true" data-bind="name: 'option-group-' + attributeID() }, checkedRadio: chosen, checkedRadioProperty: 'chosen', checkedRadioValue: false" />
```